# PyQt6 Isn't calling any events for hovering over a frame

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

My goal is to detect when a user hovers or stops hovering over a frame, but whenever I try to detect that with an eventFilter, there are just no events that get run that show that. The event IDs for hoverEnter, hoverLeave, and hoverMouseMove are 127, 128, and 129, but if you run the code, you'll see that they just don't come up. Here is the code that fails:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *


class MainApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
              
        self.setWindowTitle("Test Window")
        self.resize(300, 200)
        
        self.outerLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.outerLayout.setContentsMargins(50, 50, 50, 50)
        
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue;")
        self.innerLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.label = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setText("Example Frame")

        self.innerLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.outerLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        
        self.setLayout(self.outerLayout)
    
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == 127:
            print("hovered")
        elif event.type() == 128:
            print("no longer hovered")
        elif event.type() == 129:
            print("hover move event")
        print(event.type())
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.installEventFilter(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

My end goal here is to be able to detect when a QFrame is clicked. I was thinking I would try to do that by checking for mouse clicks, and if the mouse is hovering over the frame, trigger the function.

Comment: 1) what frame do you mean? I see a QWidget that has a QLineEdit, a QPushButton and a QTextEdit 2) what do the hovered event have to do with the clicked event?

Comment: @eyllanesc this is just an example, since this is some code I made a while ago that I was using to test, but in an actual application I want to detect when a frame is clicked, and the easiest way I could think of to do that, since there's not a way built in, is to just detect when the user clicks, and see if they are hovering over the frame. I could try to get the mouse position, and the position of the window, and the position of the frame inside the window, but this seemed easier.

Comment: 1) I recommend you restructure your post where you indicate in order: - Your basic objective, - Point out that you think that a solution is to do X (your possible solution) and - Show the code explaining that it is failing. 2) The title should point out or summarize the underlying problem, not your intent as it causes confusion. 3) You only give one line of text to your background objective, shouldn't you give more detail? 4) When I read your post I get confused, what is its objective: to detect the hovered or the clicked ?. 5) **what element do you call frame?** Your explanation is confusing.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, I didn't think about it much when writing it but I now realize everything about that post was structured badly, hopefully it's fixed now.

Comment: Do you understand that the clicked event is different from the hover event? What is your end goal? Please only enter the relevant goal.

Comment: @eyllanesc I know the click event is different from the hover event. As far as I can tell (from https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html), there is no click event, there is just self.btn.clicked, but no self.frame.clicked. There IS a hover event, so I am trying to use that to tell if the user clicks on a frame. The end goal is to detect a click on a frame. Sorry, I'm not really sure what you're confused about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it should be noted that clicked is not an event but a signal. The button clicked signal is emitted when the button receives the MouseButtonRelease event.

In this answer I will show at least the following methods to implement the clicked signal in the QFrame.

- Override mouseReleaseEvent

  ```py
  import sys

  from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
  from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget


  class Frame(QFrame):
      clicked = pyqtSignal()

      def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
          super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
          self.clicked.emit()


  class MainApp(QWidget):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.setWindowTitle("Test Window")
          self.resize(300, 200)

          self.outerLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
          self.outerLayout.setContentsMargins(50, 50, 50, 50)

          self.frame = Frame()
          self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue;")

          self.label = QLabel(text="Example Frame")

          self.innerLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
          self.innerLayout.addWidget(self.label)

          self.outerLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

          self.frame.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

      @pyqtSlot()
      def handle_clicked(self):
          print("frame clicked")


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      window = MainApp()
      window.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec())
  ```
- Use a eventFilter:

  ```py
  import sys

  from PyQt6.QtCore import QEvent
  from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget


  class MainApp(QWidget):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.setWindowTitle("Test Window")
          self.resize(300, 200)

          self.outerLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
          self.outerLayout.setContentsMargins(50, 50, 50, 50)

          self.frame = QFrame()
          self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue;")

          self.label = QLabel(text="Example Frame")

          self.innerLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
          self.innerLayout.addWidget(self.label)

          self.outerLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

          self.frame.installEventFilter(self)
          # for move mouse
          # self.frame.setMouseTracking(True)

      def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
          if obj is self.frame:
              if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
                  print("press")
              # for move mouse
              # elif event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseMove:
              #    print("move")
              elif event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease:
                  print("released")
          return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      window = MainApp()
      window.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec())
  ```

### Plus

A big part of the error of the O attempt is that by doing `window.installEventFilter(window)` it is only listening for events from the window itself and not from the QFrame. The solution is to send the QFrame events to the class `window.frame.installEventFilter(window)`.

On the other hand, do not use numerical codes but the enumerations since they are more readable.

On the other hand, for the mouse event, the `Qt::WA_Hover` attribute must be enabled(Read the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhoverevent.html) for more information)

```py
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import QEvent, Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget


class MainApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Test Window")
        self.resize(300, 200)

        self.outerLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.outerLayout.setContentsMargins(50, 50, 50, 50)

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue;")

        self.label = QLabel(text="Example Frame")

        self.innerLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.innerLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.outerLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.frame.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_Hover)
        self.frame.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.frame:
            if event.type() == QEvent.Type.HoverEnter:
                print("enter")
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Type.HoverMove:
                print("move")
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Type.HoverLeave:
                print("leave")
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: This works great and is really  informative! I didn't understand installEventFilter, since the code I saw using it was for something different, and I was calling it on the main window, instead of the frame itself. Tysm!

Comment: @Fun840 I have added more information so that you understand your error